# Django - HTML input value not printing in Views

Tags: django, forms, django-views

I want to pass an input value to views, assign variable, and print out the result.

HTML:

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
        <form class="col-sm-12" method="POST">{% csrf_token%}
            <div class="form-group row">
                <input type="text" class="col-sm-10 form-control" name='stockList'>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Append</button>
                </div>
            </div>
                {% block label %}{% endblock %}
        </form>
```

views:

```
def home(request):
print(request.POST)

if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST:
    stockPost = request.POST.get('stockList','')
    print(stockPost)
```

expected Result: when clicking submit, the terminal will display the values in 'stockList'

Actual result: the terminal does not print the values in 'stockList'

I saw some explanations regarding the queryDict but had a hard time following them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try just: if request.method == 'POST':
    stockPost = request.POST['stockList']

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work -- the terminal will not print out the value :(

Comment: "{% csrf_token%}" - maybe this is the problem, try "{% csrf_token %}"

Answer (score 0):

There was a duplicate html element with the same name as my input field. Changing the name was able to resolve the issue!

thank you for all the help!